# I'm trying to parse a Hebrew word in PHP. It looks ok as a string, but when I try to split it out into characters it won't display correctly

Tags: php, string, parsing, utf-16, hebrew

Here's my simplified test code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <?php
        //uncommenting the next line results in the whole page displaying in "chinese -simplified"
        //header("content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-16");
        header('Content-language: he');
    ?>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=UTF-16">
    <meta http-equiv="content-language" content="he-il">
</head>
<body>
<?php
        // in Production, we are grabbing the hebrew word from the database
        //$sql = "SELECT masoretic FROM codex WHERE id = 20"; // just grabs a word from the database
                                                            // it is stored using UTF16_general_ci on mySQL
        // in this test we can mock the exact same data that was copy and pasted in
        // the results were the same with the data from the db
            $masoretic = "בָּרָ֣א";

            echo $masoretic . '<br>'; // displays correctly in HEBREW = בָּרָ֣א
            // now loop through the word and process each letter
            $length = strlen($masoretic);
            // even though there are only 3 real letters, the diacritic marks count as characters, so we should get at least 7 loops
            for ($x = 0; $x <= $length; $x++) {
                $letter = substr($masoretic,0,1); // process this letter
                $masoretic = substr($masoretic, 1); // the rest of the word
                $name = '';
                $recognized = false;
                switch($letter){
                    case 'ר':
                        $recognized = true;
                        $name = 'Raysh';
                        break;
                    case 'א':
                        $recognized = true;
                        $name = 'Aleph';
                        break;
                    default:
                        $recognized = false;
                        break;
                }
                if($recognized){
                    echo ('found a ' . $name);
                    echo $letter; // for now just display it
                }else{
                        echo 'unrecognized letter:';
                        print_r($letter);
                        echo '<br>';
                }                       
            }           
    ?>
</body>
```

the page is displaying like this:

```
בָּרָ֣א
unrecognized letter:�
unrecognized letter:�
unrecognized letter:�
unrecognized letter:�
unrecognized letter:�
unrecognized letter:�
unrecognized letter:�
unrecognized letter:�
unrecognized letter:�
unrecognized letter:�
unrecognized letter:�
unrecognized letter:�
unrecognized letter:�
unrecognized letter:�
unrecognized letter:
```

I find it really strange that the full hebrew word shows up ok but each individual letter won't display. I assume there's something funky going on with the UTF16, so I added headers, but in some cases that actually made it worse. (see inline comments)

Comment: You need to use the `mb_XXX` string functions, since Hebrew letters are multi-byte.

Comment: @Barmar did you want to take any action beyond commenting ...https://stackoverflow.com/a/68386500/2943403

Comment: Related [PHP: How to split a UTF-8 string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21653033/2943403) and [Convert a String into an Array of Characters - multi-byte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55783469/2943403) and [Splitting, counting and formatting multibyte characters in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61470540/2943403) and [Php cannot find way to split utf-8 strings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8369579/2943403) and [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2590980/parsing-multibyte-string-in-php](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2590980/2943403)

Comment: You don't need `default: $recognized = false;  break;` since you default to false before the switch block.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In UTF-16 the glyphs are going to be represented by 2-4 bytes, so you need to use the multibyte-aware string functions, eg: [`mb_str_split()`.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-str-split.php)

```php
// input in in 8 and conversion to 16 since everything on SO is UTF-8
$in_8  = 'בָּרָ֣א';
$in_16 = mb_convert_encoding($in_8, 'UTF-16', 'UTF-8');

foreach(mb_str_split($in_16, 1, 'UTF-16') as $glyph_16) {
    // covert back for example display in UTF-8
    $glyph_8 = mb_convert_encoding($glyph_16, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-16');
    printf("%s %s\n",bin2hex($glyph_16), $glyph_8);
}
```

You should be able to omit the conversions in your own code, those would be for the benefit of people like me who don't work in UTF-16.

Output:

```php
05d1 ב
05b8 ָ
05bc ּ
05e8 ר
05b8 ָ
05a3 ֣
05d0 א
```

Comment: [The fundamental goal of closing duplicate questions is to help people find the right answer by getting all of those answers in one place.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates#:~:text=The%20fundamental%20goal%20of%20closing%20duplicate%20questions%20is%20to%20help%20people%20find%20the%20right%20answer%20by%20getting%20all%20of%20those%20answers%20in%20one%20place.)  I'll leave this question open so that you can demonstrate good curation as a Recognized Member of the PHP Collective should.  This question does not require a new answer on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Please see private discussion "_Recognized Members who are not putting Stack Overflow first_" in the Collective.

Comment: @ken You've likely worked past this already, but I've updated the answer to be pertinent to UTF-16 as-asked. I suppose I glossed over the specific encoding on my first read.